# How do I change the column name in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is a table created earlier in mysql, the task is to transliterate the names of columns in the table. There is a ready-made function that takes a text value and returns the result transliterated (from Cyrillic to Latin). The problem is, how do I rename columns using the command?(without using sql commands)

I tried this way (I took the command from the sqlalchemy-migrate documentation):

`name_table = Table(name_table, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine) columns_table = name_table.c.keys()`

`for col in columns_table: name_table.c.col.alter(name=translit(col))`

Where, "name_table" is the name of the table, "c" is an abbreviation of "column", "col" is the name of the column, "columns_table" is the list of column names, "translit" is the transliteration function.

The command gave an error, and if I explicitly specify the name of the column, then it worked:

`name_table.c.прайс.alter(name=translate('прайс')), where "прайс" is the name of the column in Cyrillic.`

Perhaps there is some option via session? Something like

`session.query(name_table).rename(......)`

Sorry in advance for my English, it's not my native language)

Comment: Try looking at [Python SQLAlchemy - Update table structure](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sqlalchemy-update-table-structure/?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=8CA03964BA804479AF999F3DDA059FFC).

Comment: unfortunately, the task execution consists without using the SQL language((( Thanks for the answer.

Comment: were you able to figure out a clean way to do this?